listener no longer called after nack
Given:
ConsumerFactory with ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL set.
    @KafkaListener(
            autoStartup = "false",
            topics = "someTopic",
            containerFactory = "manualAckKafkaListenerContainerFactory",
            concurrency = "8",
            batch = "true",
            clientIdPrefix = "prefix")
    @Override
    public void accept(List<Message<byte[]>> messages, Acknowledgment ack) {
        try {
            processMessages(messages);
            ack.acknowledge();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            ack.nack(0, Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        }
    }

As soon as nack is called the listener method is never called again although I have a message on the topic which has not been successfully processed yet (hence the nack-call). My assumption is that calling nack with index 0 discards the whole batch and pauses the consumer for 30 seconds and tries to reprocess the messages. How can I accomplish that? I thought this sleep parameter of nack acts like a circuit breaker while keeping the consumer alive and not causing a rebalance.
while enabling debug logs and setting concurrency to 1 I get the following log output:
2024-12-16T19:06:12.593+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 1 records
2024-12-16T19:06:12.599+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] l.a.BatchMessagingMessageListenerAdapter : Processing [GenericMessage [payload=[GenericMessage [payload=byte[326], headers={kafka_offset=0, kafka_consumer=org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory$ExtendedKafkaConsumer@60c6b27d, kafka_timestampType=CREATE_TIME, kafka_receivedPartitionId=0, kafka_receivedMessageKey=some_offer_id, kafka_receivedTopic=someTopic, kafka_receivedTimestamp=1613959321000, kafka_acknowledgment=Acknowledgment for org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords@4123971f, kafka_groupId=someListener}]], headers={id=0048a31c-d7fc-9b94-2e6f-3b477607b9d1, timestamp=1734372372599}]]
// stacktrace from the logger in above code is logged here
2024-12-16T19:06:27.655+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:27.662+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Pausing for nack sleep: [someTopic-0]
2024-12-16T19:06:27.662+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:27.675+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:27.677+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:32.680+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:32.681+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:32.682+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:37.683+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:37.684+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:37.684+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:42.685+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:42.686+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:42.686+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:47.688+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:47.688+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:47.688+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:52.689+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:52.690+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:52.690+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:06:57.692+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:06:57.694+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:06:57.694+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:07:02.696+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:07:02.696+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:07:02.697+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:07:07.698+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:07:07.702+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:07:07.702+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Still paused for nack sleep
2024-12-16T19:07:12.704+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records
2024-12-16T19:07:12.706+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Resumed after nack sleep: [someTopic-0]
2024-12-16T19:07:12.709+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Commit list: {}
2024-12-16T19:07:17.711+01:00 DEBUG 14842 --- [some-service] [        kafka-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Received: 0 records

the sleeping seems to work but the polling of records returns 0.
when debugging the polling after the nack-call I end up in LegacyKafkaConsumer's method private ConsumerRecords<K, V> poll(final Timer timer, final boolean includeMetadataInTimeout) which always returns ConsumerRecords.empty() because the Fetch is empty and the timer expires after a short time.
